# Operating System Version Prerequisite

Tags: .net, windows-installer

I have an application that requires at least Windows XP SP3.  How can I go about checking for it either in the application itself, or in the MSI, and automating the installation?

Answer (score 4):

In MSI you author a [LaunchCondition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369752%28VS.85%29.aspx) using the [Operating System Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370556%28VS.85%29.aspx)

You want to check that VersionNT > 501 or ( VersionNT = 501 and ServicePackLevel > 2 )

(tweak to meet your exact needs )

In Windows Installer XML this looks like:

```
<Product...>
  <Condition Message="[ProductName] Setup requires Windows XP SP3 or greater to install">VersionNT > 501 or ( VersionNT = 501 and ServicePackLevel > 2 ) or Installed</Condition>
...
</Product>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do this before installing, but I know that in the application code itself you can do this...

```
OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
Console.WriteLine("Platform:     " + os.Platform);
Console.WriteLine("Version:      " + os.Version);
Console.WriteLine("Service Pack: " + os.ServicePack);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Version winXpSp3 = new Version("5.1.2600.5512"); // to be checked, I don't have XP SP3 available...
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version < winXpSp3)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You need Windows XP SP3 or later");
    ...
}
```

<strike>You can use that code in a custom installer step</strike> *(apparently not, according to Christopher Painter... I leave the code anyway, it could still help someone in another context)*

Comment: Well, in Visual Studio you can create an installer with custom steps written in C#... I don't know exactly how that would work, but it's certainly possible to do it that way, and the OP mentioned .NET in the tags, so he's clearly looking for a .NET solution. Anyway, I don't think this answer deserves a downvote...

Comment: Just because something can be done doesn't mean that it should.  Read: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/4/19/Managed-Code-CustomActions-no-support-on-the-way-and-heres and http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/8/17/Zataoca-Custom-actions-are-generally-an-admission-of-failure

Comment: Think of some junior developer coming in and doing some crazy out of process, reinvent the wheel, role your own garbage that could have been 1 line of code in C# and you'll start to understand why I downvoted your answer.

Comment: I didn't read everything, but since I never tried it myself and I don't have much experience with installers, I'll assume you're right...